# Message Filter extension permissions?

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a message filter extension app using the Identity Lookup Api Framework. 
I want to know is there any way to check whether the user has enabled the app to filter unknwon and spam sms from settings -> messages -> unknown and smap.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Any update you have on it?